# How to pass "Source UID" to iptables?

Tags: iptables, firewall, uid

Through command line, am setting firewall rules using iptable binary like below:

`iptables -I PRIO_IN -p tcp -s "10.0.0.25/24" -d  "10.0.0.26/24" -j ACCEPT`

For above rule, now I need to add `source uid`.

In Iptables man page, am not seeing any option by name `source uid`

Comment: Can you please explain the *purpose*, the real problem you are trying to solve? Chances are you are interested in *owner module*, which has `-m owner --uid-owner <UID>` match, but I am not sure.

Comment: I have requirement to pass Source UID of an application to iptables. So am checking how to pass source uid of an application?

Comment: That does not answer my clarification question. There is no such thing as "source UID of an application". What **real problem** you are solving? Please, don't answer again in some "computer terms", rather explain it in words your computer-illiterate boss might have been using when assigned it to you. Do you have a program which needs to be denied or permitted access without doing the same for other programs?

Comment: Further, using a source uid on a INPUT chain is not possible, since the machine where the firewall is has no way to know the uid of a tcp connection originating on a different machine.